# C# RegEx. Replace credit card in text

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, replace

I have some text with credit card number inside, like: 
"Your credit card number is 4321432143219999, this is really your credit card!"

I need to find by RegEx this number and replace it with `************9999`, so result text should be:
"Your credit card number is `************9999`, this is really your credit card!"

How can I do it in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @jsobo I believe the OP has considered regular expressions given that (s)he said "I need to find by RegEx"

Comment: sample code of what was tried and didn't work would make this a "REAL" question.  This is a request for us to do this person's work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var str = "Your credit card number is 4321432143219999, this is really your credit card!";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, "[0-9](?=[0-9]{4})", "*");
```

This will search for digits that are followed by at least 4 digits and replace it with `*` (so it would be fooled by `123456` and it would change it in `**3456`)

If your credit card numbers are 16 digits long:

```
var res2 = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b[0-9]{12}(?=[0-9]{4}\b)", new string('*', 12));
```

This will replace a block of 12 digits followed by 4 digits (so a total of 16 digits) with 12x `*`. The digits must be separated from other text with space or other non-word characters. So `A1234567890123456` isn't good, as isn't `1234567890123456A`. `1234567890123456,` is ok because the `,` is a non-word character.

Answer (score 6):

It's best to avoid regular expressions whenever possible because they are slower and harder to troubleshoot than ordinary substring operations.

```
    public static string HideNumber(string number)
    {
        string hiddenString = number.Substring(number.Length - 4).PadLeft(number.Length, '*');
        return hiddenString;
    }
```

Comment: Good answers often include a little explanation, especially when they offer a different tech solution than the questioner requested.

Comment: ok so this is my comment - Regex is crap, dont use it when ever you can.